# Web Scrapping vs Web Scraping

Tags: debate, edições-sugeridas

Abro este tópico para debater sobre alterações gramaticais em tags relacionadas à atividade de [web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

Acredito que a terminologia correta quando queremos nos referir à atividade de vasculhar páginas na web para pegar dados, seja: `Web Scraping`, sem dobrar o "p"; no entanto, nas tags do SOpt temos `webscrapping` e `scrapping`.

Sugiro que sejam alteradas as tags: [Webscrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webscrapping) e [Scrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapping), uma vez que, de acordo com [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842324/scraping-vs-scrapping-is-there-a-difference#comment72793950_42842324), [este dicionário](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scraping), [este outro dicionário](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scraping?s=t), com o [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) e com a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping), o termo correto quando tenta-se extrair dados de páginas da web, utiliza somente uma letra "p".

Inclusive ao tentar procurar pelas tags contendo `"scrapp"` no SOen, nada é encontrado.

**tl;dr**

Alterar tags:

- webscrapping > web-scraping
- scrapping > scraping

Comment: Tem toda razão e concordo com uso de hífen também, vamos aguardar um moderador

Comment: Parece fazer sentido a mudança.

Comment: Só vale lembrar que, caso sejam muitas perguntas com essa tag, essas edições em massa deveriam ser feitas em horário de menos movimento, como a noite ou fins de semana pela manhã.

Comment: @diegofm mas o moderador pode editar sem precisar editar uma a uma :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tudo feito.

[scrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapping) e [webscrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webscrapping) foram removidas, com [scraping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scraping) e [web-scraping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) criadas no lugar, respectivamente.

Boa sugestão!